# Definition mx.formatters.DateFormatter could not be found in Flash CS4?

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-cs4, date-format

When I try to convert between date and string in Flash CS4, I use DateFormatter, I import mx.formatters.DateFormatter, but it tells me "Definition mx.formatters.DateFormatter could not be found", how to solve it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the DateFormatter is part of the Flex SDK and not part of Flash CS4. You need to include the Flex SWC file in your actionscript settings.

I found a nice little tutorial that explains everything you need to know with screenshots.

http://actionscriptexamples.com/2008/10/26/using-the-flex-sdk-with-flash-cs4/